# What is the difference between ArrayAdapter , BaseAdapter and ListAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, listadapter, baseadapter

Could you please tell me  difference between `ArrayAdapter` , `BaseAdapter` and `ListAdapter`.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**`BaseAdapter`** as the name suggests, is a base class for all the adapters.

When you are extending the Base adapter class you need to implement all the methods like `getCount()`, `getId()` etc.

**`ArrayAdapter`** is a class which can work with array of data. You need to override only `getview()` method.

**`ListAdapter`** is a an interface implemented by concrete adapter classes.

`BaseAdapter` is an abstract class whereas `ArrayAdapter` and `ListAdapter` are the concrete classes.

`ArrayAdapter` and `ListAdapter` classes are developed since in general we deal with the array data sets and list data sets.

Comment: You are correct in saying that `ArrayAdapter` is a concrete class. However, `ListAdapter` is not a class, it is an interface implemented by `BaseAdapter`. In short, you could either use the ready-made `ArrayAdapter`, or write your own adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: i've question, i want to use DataBase in my proje that fills with users data, and after filling ,all the items will be shown in ListView. but i don't know which of Adapter is usfull for me?ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter? please help me. thanks

Comment: It should be CursorAdapter please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html

Answer (score 48):

**ListAdapter**

It is an interface that extended Adapter which is the bridge between a ListView and the data that backs the list.

**BaseAdaper**

Common base class of common implementation for an Adapter that can be used in both ListView (by implementing the specialized ListAdapter interface} and Spinner (by implementing the specialized SpinnerAdapter interface.

**ArrayAdapter**

A concrete BaseAdapter that is backed by an array of arbitrary objects.

Refer below links

1. [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)
2. [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html)
3. [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: Note that ListAdapter is an interface, whereas the other two are classes that implement ListAdapter (one indirectly).

Comment: can you give an instance when will i use base and array adapter?