# Custom Adapter getView method called frequently with position 0

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I have a GridView bound to a custom ArrayAdapter derivation.

```
<GridView
        android:id="@+id/measurements"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"


        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
```

Each item is inflated to a view (I use the view-recycling pattern) as shown below.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#8800CC00">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_view_id" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_status" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/widget_timestamp" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a HandlerThread that then populates each widget with data values on a periodic basis.

However I see that the first view is 'frozen' - no updates. LogCat shows me that
adapter#getView(position = 0) is being called almost as if it's in a loop.

```
public class WidgetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DataItem>
    {
        private DataServiceProxy _dataServiceProxy;

        public WidgetAdapter(Context context, List<DataItem> objects, DataServiceProxy dataServiceProxy) {
            super(context, 0, objects);
            _dataServiceProxy = dataServiceProxy;

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View view;
                DataItem dataItem = getItem(position);

                if (convertView == null)
                {
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_dataItem, parent, false);
                    view.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                }
                else
                {
                    view = convertView;
                    int oldId = ((Integer)view.getTag()).intValue();
                    _dataServiceProxy.removeListener(WidgetView.getFor(view), oldId);
                }

                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.widget_view_id)).setText("View# " + dataItem.id);
                view.setTag(Integer.valueOf(dataItem.id));

                _dataServiceProxy.addListener(new WidgetView(view, dataItem), dataItem.id);
                return view;
        }
...
```

The last time this happened, I had fixed it - by replacing height='wrap_content' to 'match_parent' in all GridView item template sub-views. (Ref:Romain Guy's Google IO talk )

But it's back and driving me nuts...

Call stack when I set a breakpoint at the getView(pos=0) shows

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 255 in
>   WidgetFragment$WidgetAdapter))              WidgetFragment$WidgetAdapter.getView(int, View,
>   ViewGroup) line: 255      GridView(AbsListView).obtainView(int,
>   boolean[]) line: 2456     GridView.onMeasure(int, int) line: 1030 
>     GridView(View).measure(int, int) line: 15562
>     RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(View,
>   RelativeLayout$LayoutParams, int, int) line: 617
>     RelativeLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 399
>     RelativeLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15562
>     FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int,
>   int) line: 5109       FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 310
>     FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15562 
>     FrameLayout(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int, int, int,
>   int) line: 5109       FrameLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 310
>     FrameLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15562 
>     LinearLayout.measureVertical(int, int) line: 833
>     LinearLayout.onMeasure(int, int) line: 574
>     LinearLayout(View).measure(int, int) line: 15562
>     PhoneWindow$DecorView(ViewGroup).measureChildWithMargins(View, int,
>   int, int, int) line: 5109

Comment: Its a default behaviour we cant judge how many times will called

Comment: For more check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618272/custom-listview-adapter-getview-method-being-called-multiple-times-and-in-no-co/2639159#2639159

Comment: @kalyanpvs - I've already incorporated that nugget of not setting height=wrap_content in a list view item. I'm okay with it being called multiple times - what I'm seeing is multiple getView(pos=0) EVERY second

Comment: if you set to match parent there is no guarantee..match_parent will reduce the number of calls only

Comment: you need to do is check the position with 0 and if already loaded just skip it

Comment: Please post your adapter, it's easier to help you when we have the whole picture.

Comment: @einschnaehkeee - added adapter snippet. I need to have a reference to the latest view so that it can be redrawn on a async data update.

Answer (score 2):

Found a fix - not sure about the reasoning though.

By process of elimination, I ended up with knowing that the getView(pos=0) calls start pinging only after the empty textview is updated by the HandlerThread. I double checked the Thread Ids that the UI is being updated on the right thread.

I then started tweaking the attributes of the textview and the following combination makes the symptoms go away and the first view is updating correctly now. Basically **the height needs to be hard coded**, match_parent has the above mentioned problem and wrap_content is a no-no as per the android guys

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget_status" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to post that here because I cannot comment for the moment.

I have the same issue than you and what I've done is delete your adapter and recreate it.
Do it step by step like :

- create your adapter extends BaseAdapter (better than ArrayAdapter, [see why there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628742/what-is-the-difference-between-arrayadapter-baseadapter-and-listadapter) )
- implement unimplement methods
- add a list in your adapter as your datalist
- edit getCount(), getItem(), getItemId()
- edit getView() step by step (create view with LayoutInflater)
- try your app with a 2-3 data in the list

If it works, complete your adapter as you want