# When should I use BaseAdapter in Android?

Tags: android, adapter

I am working on android app in which I am using adapters to populate the data in a listview. I am confused where we should use `BaseAdapter`. I read many questions where it is written that we should use `ArrayAdapter` for arrays and arraylist that is ok and `CursorAdapter` in case of cursor.

I know `BaseAdapter` is the super class of `ArrayAdapter` and `CursorAdapter`. I have checked already this question [What is the difference between ArrayAdapter , BaseAdapter and ListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628742/what-is-the-difference-between-arrayadapter-baseadapter-and-listadapter) but it don't explain when we should use `BaseAdapter`.

When should I use `BaseAdapter` ?

Comment: BaseAdapter is a baseclass for all adapter.
CursorAdapter we mostly use in case of handling Data from Sqlite
arrayadapter is used to handle array data.

Comment: If you implements a custom adapter in order your list manages your own type of elements, it should extends BaseAAdapter. Search for custom adapter and viewholder.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628742/what-is-the-difference-between-arrayadapter-baseadapter-and-listadapter

Comment: @Riturajsuman Yes I know that I already mentioned in the question. Please read my question again.

Comment: @bigdestroyer thanks can you please give an example and explain a bit more in detail ?

Comment: Check this tuto, is a good example: http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use it:

- if your model data is not already in a data structure for which there is a concrete `ListAdapter` class, and
- if you determine that creating a custom adapter will be better for the user, or perhaps less development work for you, than would be reorganizing your data structure

For example, suppose that you use `JSONArray` to parse a snippet of JSON. `JSONArray` does not implement the `List` interface, and therefore you cannot use it with `ArrayAdapter`. None of the other adapters match. Yet, you want to show this `JSONArray` in an `AdapterView`. In that case, your choices are:

- roll through the data and convert it into an `ArrayList`, so you can use `ArrayAdapter`, or
- create a custom subclass of `BaseAdapter` that can adapt a `JSONArray` (a `JSONArrayAdapter`)
- stop using `JSONArray` and instead use something else for parsing your JSON, like Gson, which can populate a `List` directly, allowing you to use `ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 3):

If your data is available in a [`Collection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html) you can go with an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). (use the [`addAll`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#addAll(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20T%3E)) method to put your data in the adapter)

If your data is not in a `Collection`: then you can't and you must find another adapter that suits your needs. (typically: use a [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) when data comes from a database)

If you can't find any existing adapter working fine with your data structure/data source : you can write a subclass of [`BaseAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) to support your own data structure.

If you plan to display your data in a [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) (this is a common use-case): then you must ensure that your adpter also implements [`ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) (because the [`ListView` needs a `ListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter))).

Note that `ArrayAdapter` and `CursorAdapter` implements `ListAdapter`.